# Capture unique id in router.post fastapi

Tags: python, gunicorn, fastapi

I am trying to capture the time taken by api using fastapi in python with below method:

```
import string, time, random, logging
from starlette.requests import Request

@app.middleware("http")
async def log_requests(request: Request, call_next):
    idem = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=6))
    logger.info(f"rid={idem} start request path={request.url.path}")
    start_time = time.time()
    response = await call_next(request)
    process_time = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000
    formatted_process_time = '{0:.2f}'.format(process_time)
    logger.info(f"rid={idem} completed_in={formatted_process_time}ms status_code={response.status_code}")
    return response
```

I want to capture the unique id `idem` in `@router.post` section written as follows but it is giving error:

```
import logging as log

@router.post("/infer/", response_description="AD Data Infer")
async def ad_infer_algorithm(ad_infer_config: ADInferConfigSchema = Body(...)):
  log.info("Executing AD Train Algorithm with config"+idem)
  return "2"
```

Kindly help

Comment: If you want to attach metadata to the request, you can do `request.state.idem = idem` in `log_requests`, then add `request: Request` as a parameter to `ad_infer_algoritm` and retrieve it with `request.state.idem` there again. Does that work for you?

Comment: @MatsLindh this works flawlessly.just instead of in comment, write this in proper way so that i can accept your answer as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastAPI has a `state` attribute on the `request` object. This allows you to attach state to a request from a middleware, and then access that state in your controller (or in another middleware).

Since you already have the `request` object available in your middleware, you can just attach `idem` to the request state there:

```py
async def log_requests(request: Request, call_next):
    idem = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=6))
    request.state.idem = idem
```

(Side note: you can probably replace that `random.choices` call with `secrets.token_urlsafe` to get a randomly generated identifier (unless you need to control upper vs lower case identifiers - since you didn't include ascii_lowercase).

You can then access that state in your view controller:

```py
@router.post("/infer/", response_description="AD Data Infer")
async def ad_infer_algorithm(request: Request, ad_infer_config: ADInferConfigSchema = Body(...)):
  log.info("Executing AD Train Algorithm with config" + request.state.idem)
  return "2"
```

(Another side note: the logging commands should usually use placeholders (`%s`) and then the variables as arguments: `log.info("Executing AD Train Algorithm with config %s", request.state.idem)`